# How to pass null argument in Android Databinding

Tags: android-databinding

Why can't pass null value? how can fix it? I can't find any hint from [Document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/?hl=ko).

**ERROR**

****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method onClick(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) in class kr.co.app.MyActivity.MyListener file:/Users/jujaeho/projects/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_my.xml loc:24:71 - 24:106 ****\ data binding error ****

**CODE**

```
class MyActivity {
  interface MyListener {
    fun onClick(abc: ABC?, count: Int?)
  }
}

<layout>
  <data>
  <variable
    name="handler"
    type="kr.co.app.MyActivity.MyListener" />
  </data>
  <View
    ...
    android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onClick(null, null)}" />
</layout>
```

Comment: If problem was with `null` handler there should be NPE. But according to posted error, problem is connected to wrong method signature of `MyListener` interface

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just encountered this problem today, and what I did basically was to cast the `null` parameters to the types expected in the method parameters. In your case, this should be something like:

```
<layout>
  <data>
  <import type="ABC" /> // just an illustration, specify the full package
  <variable
    name="handler"
    type="kr.co.app.MyActivity.MyListener" />
  </data>
  <View
    ...
    android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onClick((ABC) null, (int) null)}" />
</layout>
```

I am not sure about the `int` casting, but you can try it or use the `Integer` wrapper class for casting.

Comment: int casting doesn't work because in java an int can't be null you have to use Integer.

Answer (score 1):

if you are intending to pass null why cannot you assign default value for your onClick method

```
class MyActivity {
  interface MyListener {
    fun onClick(abc: ABC?=null, count: Int?=null)
  }
}
```

you can pass nothing if you want to pass null

Comment: I think android databinding under the Java. So handling default value is some difficult. while we can type `@JvmOverloads` above the method, but this is not allowed in interface.

Comment: but i am able to pass null to my parameters inside interface. The only difference is that it's  a separate file not with inside activity